# how to use robocopy in batch-file?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

i am trying to use following robocopy command in batch file.

robocopy "C:\Dell" "C:\Dell\av tsp" /copy:dat /maxage:1

when i execute the batch file it executes recursively and does not stop. please help

Comment: Don't call the batch file `robocopy.bat` - we all learn that problem at some time. :)

Comment: tried using other name still facing same problem

Comment: You still have a `robocopy.bat` someplace by the look of it.

Comment: no robocopy.bat exists. please help

Comment: I can't see your screen or your folder, to see what the problem is.

Comment: well, what do you expect when you copy a folder into itself?